# Array inaccessible only at certain times

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am currently building a parallax background effect in Unity and starting with some starter code that I'm trying to work though. The code works for the most part, with some small issues I'm slowly getting through.

I have been testing out various stats of public vs. private, etc. but can't seem to work out exactly why and where the issue I'm facing is occurring.

When I run the same script and it calls Update() every frame, I would expect to have the same size "poolObjects" length. However, when I call it with a starting pool size of 10, I get 10, then 2, then 0, then 10, 2, 0, etc.

I am truncating it but posting what I think to be relevant here. Hope you can help me see what is likely obvious!

I do see "In GetPool Object" but because the length is never > 0, I never see within the For Loop, which is essential. I can't figure out why the poolObjects length would be showing up as 0.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallaxer : MonoBehaviour {

    class PoolObject {
        public Transform transform;
        public bool inUse;
        public PoolObject(Transform t) { transform = t; }
        public void Use() { inUse = true; }
        public void Dispose() { inUse = false; }
    }
...
    public int poolSize;
    public float shiftSpeed;
    public float spawnRate;
...

    float spawnTimer;
    PoolObject[] poolObjects;
    float targetAspect;
    GameManager game;

    void Awake() {
        Configure();
    }

    void Start() {
        game = GameManager.Instance;
    }
...
    void Update() {
        Debug.Log(poolObjects.Length + "Len here of pool objects");
        if (game.GameOver) return;

        Shift();
        spawnTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnTimer > spawnRate) {
            Spawn();
            spawnTimer = 0;
        }
    }

    void Configure() {
        //spawning pool objects
        targetAspect = targetAspectRatio.x / targetAspectRatio.y;
        // targetAspect = Camera.main.aspect;
        // Debug.Log(targetAspectRatio.x +" " +  targetAspectRatio.y);
        poolObjects = new PoolObject[poolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(Prefab) as GameObject;
            Transform t = go.transform;
            t.SetParent(transform);
            t.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
            poolObjects[i] = new PoolObject(t);
        }

        if (spawnImmediate) {
            SpawnImmediate();
        }
    }

    void Spawn() {
        //moving pool objects into place
        Transform t = GetPoolObject();
        Debug.Log("In to Spawn" + t);
        if (t == null) return;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.y = Random.Range(ySpawnRange.minY, ySpawnRange.maxY);
        pos.x = (defaultSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect;
        // Debug.Log("Spwaning");
        // Debug.Log(Camera.main.aspect);
        // Debug.Log(immediateSpawnPos.x + " " + immediateSpawnPos.y + " " + targetAspect);
        t.position = pos;
        // Debug.Log(pos);
    }

    void SpawnImmediate() {
        Transform t = GetPoolObject();
        if (t==null) return;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.y = Random.Range(ySpawnRange.minY, ySpawnRange.maxY);
        pos.x = (immediateSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect;
        t.position = pos; 
        Spawn();
    }

    void Shift() {
        //loop through pool objects 
        //moving them
        //discarding them as they go off screen
        Debug.Log(poolObjects.Length + "Finding Length");
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {

            poolObjects[i].transform.position += -Vector3.right * shiftSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(poolObjects[i].transform.position);
            CheckDisposeObject(poolObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    void CheckDisposeObject(PoolObject poolObject) {
        //place objects off screen
        if (poolObject.transform.position.x < (-defaultSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect) {
            poolObject.Dispose();
            poolObject.transform.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
        }
    }

    Transform GetPoolObject() {
        //retrieving first available pool object
        Debug.Log("In GetPool Object" + poolObjects.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {
            Debug.Log("This is not showing up "+ poolObjects[i].inUse);
            if (!poolObjects[i].inUse) {
                poolObjects[i].Use();
                return poolObjects[i].transform;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the poolSize is originally: 10. Shiftspeed: 1, spawnRate: 20

Comment: I guess there are 3 Parallaxer objects in the scene.

Comment: Normally with pooled objects you dont destroy them you reuse them. but, surely you dont want to dispose of your poolobject, but the object it is hosting?  So that the pool spot is open for the next?

Comment: @DanFein can you confirm that what shingo said is not the case?

Comment: Wow you guys are legends!! Thank you @Shingo, glad I asked!!!